# Parsing System.Object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell command that returns an object from an `Invoke-RestMethod` that is doing an HTTP Get. If I echo the return it looks like this:

```
policies
--------
{@{id=12345; name=xxxx; ... }
```

I want to parse out the value of `id`. What approach would I take to accomplish this?

Comment: Echo the return type -- Object.GetType() (callable that way in powershell, I think?) will tell you the type of object is returned. Then you will know how to handle it, and if not, [edit] and say what type is returned.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in @Will comment -> Use `Get-Member` to get the object type, like:

```
$returnVal = Invoke-RestMethod ...
$returnVal | Get-Member
```

This should return the type of the returned object (including methods and properties you're able to call on the object).
It seems that `policies` might be a dictionary, but I'm not sure. If it is a dictionary you can try:

```
$returnVal = Invoke-RestMethod ...
$dict = $returnVal | select -ExpandProperty policies
$id = $dict.Get_Item("id")
```

If it is simple JSON you can deserialize it via:

```
$returnVal = Invoke-RestMethod ...
$derserializedJsonObject = $returnVal | select policies | ConvertTo-Json
```

Hope that helps

Comment: $dict.Get_Item didn't work... Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'Get_Item'